Redux Store - Access entire slice
Objective: Access the latest data from a slice in my Redux store in response to user input.
The Program: A React and Redux application, which has a button on a page. Upon being pressed, the button is meant to dump the state of a Redux slice to the user.
Problem: When user input triggers my onclick callback function, the actual state of mySlice is not accessible via my selector.  I've tried const mySliceSelector = useSelector((state) => state.mySlice); and tested this by doing console.log(JSON.stringify(mySliceSelector)) inside the callback, and it just prints the initial state of the slice.  Any changes that have been made to the slice since its conception are not shown.
Here is a snippet of my code, for better context:
    // mySlice is modified over time by other parts of the code
    const mySliceSelector = useSelector((state) => state.mySlice);
    
    const handleClick = async () => { // This is called by a button
        console.log(JSON.stringify(mySliceSelector));
    }

The arrays and data inside the slice are empty when printed as if haven't changed since the program started, even though they have changed.
Setup: I have a slice, which contains arrays and objects in its state. This slice can be changed from various actions taken by the user. On a specific page, I want to be able to display the entire contents of the slice to the user if they click a button. I attempt to JSON.stringify() a selector I have for that slice (see above), but it prints the initial state unless I trigger a re-render of the page where this button lives.

Please [edit] to clarify what the specific issue/problem is, and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so readers and better understand what any code is doing and when and why it's doing it.

No, thank you, what is requested here is a complete [mcve] of the relevant code that reproduces the problem you describe. useSelector((state) => state.mySlice); returns the current state.mySlice. When that state is updated in the store a rerender is triggered and again the current value is selected and returned. We need more detail from you.

Based on your description my best guess is that you've a Javascript closure issue with handleClick and need to show where and how it's used.

Maybe it is a closure issue, but I can access any other useSelector that I've set up within this callback.  It just seems to be the fact that I'm trying to subscribe to an entire slice, which somehow means that no re-renders are triggered on each update.  As per my answer below, useStore allows me to grab a snapshot of the current state which I can then read for my own purposes.  Thank you!

The solution
My problem did not require me to subscribe to state updates for the slice.  Thus, useSelector() was unhelpful.  After looking over the documentation again, I found useStore().  The following line of code allows me to read the current state of an entire slice, which I then print out in response to a click event:
     import { useStore } from 'react-redux';
...
    const reduxStore = useStore();
    
    const handleClick = async () => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(reduxStore.getState().mySlice));
    }


You'r questions is not clear do you want to access the whole data of you'r store if so you can just access like this.
    const mySliceSelector = useSelector((state) => state);

regarding your issue it's better you put the whole context when are you calling this call back which you are referring handleClick
ideally you should get the latest data but for some reason if it's not their try to check the flow of you'r component logic.

A selector function that simply returns its input is almost never correct, and a selector function that returns the entire root state is absolutely never correct. See identity function state check. Looks like you meant to post this as a comment to the OP asking for better details since it doesn't answer the question.

Thank you for the response.  As stated in my post, I do not want the whole Redux state.  I am trying to get an entire slice, however, which is why I tried to select mySlice via (state) => state.mySlice.  This solution does not work for me, as the code is unable to access the latest data in that slice when it runs.
